# How do I call a function with an optional and an *args arguments?

Tags: python, function, winapi, args

How do I call my function

```
def press(clickLeft=False, *args):
    buttons = {'Enter': 0x0D, 'Ctrl': 0x11, 'a': 0x41,'c': 0x43, 'v': 0x56}
    codes = [buttons[b] for b in args]
    for b in codes:
        win32api.keybd_event(b, 0,0,0)
    if clickLeft:
        click()
```

If I call it like this

```
press('Ctrl', clickLeft=True)
```

It gives an error

```
TypeError: press() got multiple values for argument 'clickLeft'
```

Comment: optional arguments must come *last*

Comment: @DeepSpace The first one doesn't work becuase the positional argument follows the keyword one. The second one works, thank you! I am so used to writing keyword arguments in full though. I wonder if I could do it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pythononic convention is for arguments to go before keyword arguments (kwargs). So if you move your `args` to go before your optional/keyword arguments that should solve the problem:

```
def press(*args, clickLeft=False):
   pass
```

Then you call it as you suggested:

```
press('Ctrl', clickLeft=True)
```